# C++ Methoden Methods Call with +1

Tags: c++

Hello I have a small question that I can't find an answer to on the internet.

**Question:**

What makes this 1+method name:

```
int rekursion (int p,int q,int& rest){
    return(1+rekursion (p-q,q,rest));
}
```

Normally I program Java and not C++ and I have never come across this before.

Comment: It adds one to the results of calling the method. It would do the same in Java.

Comment: Given your mention of "method name", perhaps `1 + rekursion(p-q,q,rest)` would be clearer than `1+rekursion (p-q,q,rest)` (only use of spaces changed)

Comment: It would be an infinite loop in both C++ and Java

Comment: This is an infinite recursion that will result in *Stack Overflow* error, both in C++ and Java.

Comment: (It may be written like this for tail call optimization, although as noted since there’s no terminating condition, it’d be a different kind of failure.)

Comment: @prapin Depends on computer optimization.